# Configure an Android application using property file

Tags: android

I have an Android application that I need to install on diffferent devices with different configurations. I kept it in the `res/raw` folder, with data stored in `key=value` format. Can I access the value by passing the key? Can I change the `.properties` file from outside the application? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). You can predefine a `SharedPreference` file and ship your application with it. You just need to implement a way to alter those preferences to your desired extent.

It is a XML file using `key:value` pairs.

Comment: i have created the sharedpreference and stored and received the data from it... but i couldn't find the file folder to edit it from outside the application

Answer (score 0):

After the application is compiled, you can not alter the resources. That would require you to decompile the app, modify the resource then recompile it; not worth the hassle.
Also, the `default.properties` file ain't exists in the `.apk`